# How to resolve mongodb collection.find before an if state on a post call in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a problem where I'm trying to query a collection called searchLog (db.search_log = searchLog) using db.collection.find() method but it's not returning anything despite the desired item being in the database. I was googling and it seems like this may be related to the asynchronous nature of the collection.find()... I would like to ask if there is a way around this problem. Thank you.

```
  app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    let bookName = req.body.book;
    let queriedResult = searchLog.find({'name': bookName });

    if (!queriedResult) {
        // If queriedResult is not empty, do something
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo `db.collection.find` returns a Promise. You can use `async/await` to resolve find promise

```js
 app.post('/', async(req, res) => {
    let bookName = req.body.book;
    let queriedResult = await searchLog.find({'name': bookName });

    if (!queriedResult) {
        // If queriedResult is not empty, do something
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }    
});
```